# Bayes' theorem condition

Tags: statistics, bayes-theorem

Bayes theorem can be proved using the definition of conditional probability. Given events $A,B$ and $P(B)>0$ we have:

$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(AB)}{P(B)}$$

where $AB$ means the intersection of $A$ and $B$.

Bayes' theorem can then be derived using $P(AB)=P(A|B)P(B)$. But this assumes that $P(B)>0$. Now since $P(AB)=P(BA)$ we directly find:

$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}.$$

Now the problem is as follows. The book I use (Wasserman) does not state that $P(A)>0$ although we defined $P(B|A)$. My feeling is that both $P(A),P(B)$ should be larger than zero so that condition probability is well-defined. Hopefully someome can tell me where I am wrong or that I am actually right and the book is not precise on this point.

Comment: I don´t see any reason why $P(A)>0$, since $P(A|B)$ can be zero. This is the case if $A$ and $B$ do not intersect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only constraint is $P(B) > 0$ since all probabilities lie on the interval $[0, 1]$, and $P(B)$ cannot be $0$ (otherwise, we would be dividing by zero!)

There is no reason for $P(A)$ to be zero. For example, let $A$ be the event that an apple starts flying. Let $B$ be the event that I roll a $3$ on a dice. Then,

$$P(A \mid B) = \frac{P(B \mid A)\cdot P(A)}{P(B)} = 0$$

This result is intuitive. An event with probability $0$ will remain $0$, even if we gain new information.

Comment: But what about $P(B|A)$? You cannot simply set the equation equal to zero because $P(A)=0$ unless you show that $P(B|A)$ is finite larger than zero or equal to zero.

Comment: $0 < P(B\mid A) < 1$

Comment: But is this well-defined if $P(A)=0$? My feeling says that $P(B|A)=P(AB)/0$ will not be finite by definition of conditional probability. Could you prove that this can still be finite?